# How to style the html dropdown

Tags: html, css

code:

```
 <select name="xyz" id="abc">
       <option value="x">10/Page</option>
       <option value="y">20/Page</option>
       <option value="z">30/Page</option>
  </select>
```

```css
select {
  display: flex;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

option {
  background: #f4f9fb;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="xyz" id="abc">
  <option value="x">10/Page</option>
  <option value="y">20/Page</option>
  <option value="z">30/Page</option>
</select>
```

I had tried this code to change the styling of the select option, but nothing happened

expected result:

[image: expected result]

Comment: Where would the `✓` come from? You would need a widget to make it look like that

Answer (score 1):

By default, you can't change the default user interface of some controllers like select, radio, checkbox. each browser has its own user agent style for them.
so you should create a custom one.
to reach this, you should hide the main controller with `display:none` style, and then create your own controller with `label`,`span`, or whatever you want.
then, for connecting the custom controller with the main controller, you can use `for` attribute.

```
<select id="myselect">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>

<label for="myselect">
  <span>1</span>
 <span>2</span>
 <span>3</span>
</label>
```

then you just need to style the custom controller to make it like a select box.

Answer (score 0):

I use bootstrap-select for doing that like:

```js
$(function () {
        $('select').selectpicker();
    });
```

```html
 <!-- Bootstrap JS-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css"> 
 
 <select name='select' class="form-control" multiple="true" >
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option> 
 </select>
```

Reference plugin [here](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/)